# Unable to access nested collection firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build an application in Node and Express. I am able to fetch all the data and get specific document properties. However,I am unable to do 2 things:

1. Make the async method return data as an array so that I could use it instead if having to make multiple calls.
2. Get values from the collections within each individual document.

Please help me out guys. Below is how I am currently referencing the nested collection.

```js
const fetchAllGoals = async (req, res, next) => {
  /**
   * Sends a request to Firestore for a specific user's goal collection data.
   * This is accomplished by reading req.params.uid which is value passed after the /
   * All goals are pushed to the goalsArray
   * I then return the data as an api response.
   */
  try {
    let id = req.params.uid;
    const goals = await firestore.collection(
      "users/" + req.params.uid + "/goals"
    );
    const data = await goals.get();
    const goalsArray = [];
    data.forEach((doc) => {
      const goal = doc.data();
      console.log(goal);

      goalsArray.push(goal);
    });
    res.json({ data: goalsArray });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you already have?

Comment: Check it out above.

Comment: Can you pls explain a little bit more what you want to do. You get the data as array and return it as such? Do youhave any errors or do you want to do more with your code?

Comment: I have a user collection with documents, each user document has a goals collection. I would like to fetch the user document data plus the the goal data.